# How to deploy rails applicaiton in windows 10/11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, iis

I have built a **rails application** for a friend which he **doesn't have enough access to Internet**, he has a PC with windows 10 installed, he **wants to access his application offline**, How do I deploy the application to his windows, I did searched a lot and didn't found a propper solution to it, what I want is to deploy the application and whenever he restarts the pc it automatically starts and he should be able to access it without running `rails server`

I tried IIS with **Microsoft Web platfrom installer**, which seems to be retired, and I tried to use it's offline version, and wasn't able to donwload the services, I am so fraustrated. anyone has an Idea of any web server for windows, or any other solution to this..., thanks and much appreciated it.

Comment: Pack up as a Linux container https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-ruby-on-rails-application and then he can host the container on his machine easily.

Comment: Microsoft Web platfrom installer installs some APIs in iis, if you want to install iis, you can refer to this link: [Installing IIS](https://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8). but iis can't publish the local project to another computer, Have you considered publishing it locally and then accessing it through another computer?

Comment: Thank you @samwu, Microsoft Web platform installer is retired, and I tried to use its offline version, but it didn't load all the services, I want to publish it on his own computer where he can access it locally.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi I will try to look into it.

Comment: If you want to deploy to localhost, this link mat help you: [configure IIS with ruby on rails app on windows server](https://qiita.com/alokrawat050/items/d757b23a063435a2619c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions and help, I finally solved it with Electron,
I create an desktop version of my rails application with Electron, and then setup the bash so that before starting or fetching data, change directory to the project folder and run the Rails server, that's it.